# Touch-pad and keyboard freeze intermittently in Windows 8, Ubuntu and even in BIOS

Tags: laptop, keyboard, freeze, touchpad

My Keyboard and touch-pad freeze intermittently: about every second (regularly), for half a second approximately. What is even more interesting, is that:

1) it happens also in linux and in BIOS

2) it does not happen when using external mouse and keyboard (USB plugged).

It is so annoying that even writing this text becomes difficult, as many keystrokes get skipped because of the freeze.

I have tried to use Windows 8 hardware troubleshooting but I had no luck. 
I have opened the task manager to try and spot any weird CPU usage correlated with the freeze, but I didn't find anything, except that the average CPU consume is slightly higher (few percents) when using the touch-pad than when using the external mouse.

I have absolutely no idea what may cause this, so I don’t know what further specific information I could give you (maybe you can suggest me), except that my laptop is an asus N56VV (with double boot for win 8 and ubuntu), that I did not change any hardware. 
I also cannot locate exactly the time this problem started occurring, since I have been using external keyboard and mouse for three months now (and before that, nothing like this ever happened).

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off *Palmcheck* option in your Mouse settings. Refer this link for turning off plamcheck: [How to Turn Off Palm Check In windows](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21662-touchpad-palmcheck-turn-off-windows.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.